# Why are some numbers converted after load data local infile?

Tags: mysql

I have the following setup:

```
> show create table nums;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                       |
|-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| nums  | CREATE TABLE `nums` (                                              |
|       |   `num` decimal(15,8) DEFAULT NULL                                 |
|       | ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ cat num_file
8.04
$ echo "load data local infile 'num_file' into table nums (@num) 
set num=truncate(@num,8);" | mysql
```

I would expect that the table would contain 8.04, but instead:

```
> select * from nums;
+------------+
| num        |
|------------|
| 8.03999999 |
+------------+
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Let's see the input value.  Do you really need to truncate, not round?  Do the input values have more than 8 decimal places?

Comment: @RickJames I tried reducing the problem to its simplest reproducible form, even though the inputs have some more variety than given. The requirement to truncate was given by the client, in cases where the input values have more than 8 decimal places (some inputs do); I agree that round would be a better choice. The example of 8.04 as input is an actual input value.

Comment: Can there be negative numbers?  How many digits might exist before the decimal place?   To follow the letter of the request, you will probably have to use string maniuplation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the issues:

- mysql's `load data` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) indicates "LOAD DATA regards all input as strings", so "8.04" is being read as a string, not a numeral
- `truncate()` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) indicates "When the first argument is of any floating-point type or of any non-numeric type, the return type is always DOUBLE"

  - Since a string is a non-numeric type, truncate is returning a DOUBLE, which is an approximated value; as the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) indicates, "floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values".

To solve this, you can `cast` the input to decimal so `truncate()` will return a decimal; as the `truncate()` documentation states, "When the first argument is a DECIMAL value, the return type is also DECIMAL":

```
set num=truncate(cast(@num as decimal(15,8)),8)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will round in the cast, leaving nothing for truncate to do:  truncate(cast('8.123456789' as decimal(15,8)),8) --> 8.12345679.

Comment: @RickJames good catch; what do you think would be a better approach?

Comment: Truncation via character manipulation would be messy and risky.  Maybe the Customer does not know the technical difference between "truncate" and "round".  If these are latitude/longitude values, then 8 decimal places is gross overkill.